# I keep getting a syntax error in else - need help Python creating a vector calculator if the user put the wrong input

Tags: python

```
if force > 1:
    try:
      force = int(input("\033[2;0H Force (numbers only): "))

    except ValueError:
      print("that's not a real number")
    continue

    else:
      break
```

Comment: `continue` should in accordingly `except` indent

Comment: @Tomerikoo - `try` `except` `else` is valid python syntax.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Indeed!!! I was too quick to draw there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `break` outside loops, bad indentation, get inside `while` loop:

```
while True:
    try:
      force = int(input("\033[2;0H Force (numbers only): "))
    except ValueError:
      print("that's not a real number")
      continue
    else:
      break
```